# Reading NodeType Value of xml file

Tags: c#, xmlnode

I have an xml file like this:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
 <DocumentVersion>1.00</DocumentVersion>
 </Header>
<MessageType>AllOrdersReport</MessageType>
<Message>
     <Order>
      <OrderID>14-7005-04201</OrderID>
      <MerchantOrderID>14-7005-04201</MerchantOrderID>
      <PurchaseDate>2020-07-28T02:32:38+00:00</PurchaseDate>
      <LastUpdatedDate>2020-07-28T14:58:07+00:00</LastUpdatedDate>
      <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>
      <SalesChannel>Amazon.com</SalesChannel>
      <FulfillmentData>
         <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
         <ShipServiceLevel>Expedited</ShipServiceLevel>
         <Address>
            <City>SAN JOSE</City>
            <State>CA</State>
            <PostalCode>95129-3137</PostalCode>
            <Country>US</Country>
         </Address>
     </FulfillmentData>
     <IsBusinessOrder>false</IsBusinessOrder>
     <OrderItem>
        <AmazonOrderItemCode>4494901738</AmazonOrderItemCode>
        <ASIN>B0N1QG</ASIN>
        <SKU>CH-4219</SKU>
        <ItemStatus>Shipped</ItemStatus>
        <ProductName>Drawing Pad</ProductName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <ItemPrice>
           <Component>
              <Type>Principal</Type>
              <Amount currency="USD">14.98</Amount>
           </Component>
           <Component>
              <Type>Tax</Type>
              <Amount currency="USD">1.39</Amount>
           </Component>
        </ItemPrice>
     </OrderItem>
  </Order>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>```
````

C# code to read the value of each tag. I'm using XmlTextReader to parse through the XML file. Update with the full code below.

````
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace democonsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader("");

            while (xtr.Read())
          {
            
            if (xtr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xtr.Name == "City")
            {
              string s7 = xtr.ReadElementContentAsString();
              Console.WriteLine("City ="+s7);
            }
             if (xtr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xtr.Name == "Type")
            {
              {
                  string s8 = xtr.ReadElementContentAsString();
                  xtr.ReadToFollowing("Amount");
                  decimal amount = xtr.ReadElementContentAsDecimal();
                  Console.WriteLine("Tax =" + amount);
              } 
            }

          }
        }
    }
}```
````

With the code below, I'm trying to get just the tax amount but keep extracting the "Principal" amount too. I'll attach a photo for reference.

How do I just show the Tax amount? Thanks for any help to a newbie!

[VSC -Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Idmd.jpg)

Comment: You will have to find an `Element` with name `Component` & then do some trickery in order to get the value. Could it be possible that you give a slightly more complete source code that will allow us do some quick debugging?

Comment: Thanks, Efthymios for looking at my problem. I have updated with the full source code for quick debugging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading xml child tag value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928930/reading-xml-child-tag-value)

Comment: Alexander, yes it answers the problem but it pulls the principal price too. Click on the "VSC-Output link above -I'm not sure how to get only the tax price. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the problem but Alexander in the above comments has already given a solution for this. The link of the previous post ([Reading xml child tag value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928930/reading-xml-child-tag-value)).

I just combined the 2 programs and done a small alteration so that you can get discretely labeled both the Tax amount & the Principal amount. This would look like:

```
XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader("xml.txt");

while (xtr.Read())
{

    if (xtr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xtr.Name == "City")
    {
        string s7 = xtr.ReadElementContentAsString();
        Console.WriteLine("City =" + s7);
    }

    if (xtr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xtr.Name == "Component")
    {
        xtr.ReadToFollowing("Type");

        string s8 = xtr.ReadElementContentAsString();
        if (s8 == "Tax")
        {
            xtr.ReadToFollowing("Amount");
            decimal amount = xtr.ReadElementContentAsDecimal();
            Console.WriteLine("Tax Amount =" + amount);
        }
        else if (s8 == "Principal")
        {
            xtr.ReadToFollowing("Amount");
            decimal amount = xtr.ReadElementContentAsDecimal();
            Console.WriteLine("Principal Amount =" + amount);
        }
    }
}
```

You will see that the end result is:

```
City =SAN JOSE
Principal Amount =14.98
Tax Amount =1.39
```

Comment: Thanks, Efthymios! This solves my problem, I was missing the 'else if' statement. Thanks for all your help